# Set foreground color in FrameLayout in Android programmatically

Tags: android, colors, foreground

I want to set foreground color in FrameLayout programmatically (not in XML attribute). I have the color codes in `RGB`

How can I convert color to drawable:

```
frm.setForeground(Drawable);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create a `Drawable` from color:

```
final int color = 0xFFFF0000;
final Drawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(color);
```

Comment: for transparent just   .setForeground(null);

Comment: For color from resources would be `new ColorDrawable( context.getResources().getColor( color))`.

Answer (score 4):

Create `Drawable` from Color Using `ContextCompat`

```
int color = R.color.black_trans_60;
frm.setForeground(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, color)));
```

Use `ContextCompat` instead of direct color as in new API `ColorDrawable` takes `ColorDrawable(@ColorInt int color)`