# Navigation Drawer Layout overlapping with frame layout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

whenever i open my navigation drawer frame layout contents are getting shown in background i even tried setting the frame's color white

**main_activity.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
tools:context="com.example.sumanravi.knowmycity.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_layout"
        android:background="@color/white">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Setting the *background* color to white will still show the contents of any view. If you want to hide the contents of a view, you should set its visibility to `View.GONE` or `View.VISIBLE` using `View#setVisibility(int)`

Comment: great this is working but it takes some time to make the contents visible and invisible whenever the drawer is opened or closed, please help me with this

Comment: Okay then, I'll answer it fully now :)

Comment: Btw, you should accept the answer if it worked for you so that we can close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to do is to hide the contents of a layout, you can:

1. Hide the whole layout (setting visibility to `View.GONE` or `View.VISIBLE`)
2. Change the alpha (setting alpha on the layout itself)
3. Remove all of the layout's children (please don't use this method, it's stupidly slow)

Containing views will always have their parent's background drawn underneath them. Another fun way to hide the content is to use the drawer listener: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html#onDrawerSlide(android.view.View, float) - look for `onDrawerSlide(View, float)` method and (for example) change the View's alpha as you go.

Another thing you could do with FrameLayouts is to set the foreground: [set forground color in framelayout in android programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474745/set-forground-color-in-framelayout-in-android-programatically)

But generally, content under navigation drawers is always (at least partially) visible. If you're trying to hide it, you're probably not following [the guide](https://material.google.com/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).